# Google Maps is not loading completely

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, google-api

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/390dpf85/) so it is much more easier

I have a slide div to reveal google maps when a button click which I integrated using Google API.

My question is: if you click the button the maps loads correctly. but after that if you hide the map by clicking again on the button and view it again by clicking the button the map doesn't load correctly. any idea how to fix this? help is really appreciated.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.map-triangle').find('div').click(function() {
    $('.map-slide').slideToggle('slow', initialize());
  });


  //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

```css
.map-triangle {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.map-triangle > div {
  background: green;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.map-triangle > div:hover {
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
.map-anchor:hover > .map-triangle > div {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.map-slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 2">
    <a href="#" class="map-anchor">
      <div class="map-triangle">
        <div>
          map
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 map-slide">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: snippet also working

Comment: google map require map to be visible on load, hook to the idle event and hide it when it loads

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/390dpf85/3/

Comment: wow thanx. removing the brackets from function call helped.

Comment: For better UX: https://jsfiddle.net/390dpf85/5/ Credits to @sarepta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to refresh `var map` after it slideToggle. If not you'll got trouble resize of your map into disposition. So to solve that you need place `var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);` after your slideToggle.

Please check this out. Hope it will help you :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  $('.map-triangle').find('div').click(function() {
    $('.map-slide').slideToggle('slow');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  });

});
```

```css
.map-triangle {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.map-triangle > div {
  background: green;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.map-triangle > div:hover {
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
.map-anchor:hover > .map-triangle > div {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.map-slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 2">
    <a href="#" class="map-anchor">
      <div class="map-triangle">
        <div>
          map
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 map-slide">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```